# Laravel Authentication with external APIs

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, api, authentication

i have external server api made with node js and mongo. 
suppose user api is localhost:8010/api/login output 
how do i use for auth in laravel ?

```
"users": [
  {
    "_id": "592e71bc05be3c26f6bda51d",
    "updatedAt": "2017-05-31T07:33:16.608Z",
    "createdAt": "2017-05-31T07:33:16.608Z",
    "userToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiRW1qb3kiLCJkYXRlIjoxNDk2MjE1OTk2NTk0fQ.25AY8EGoCmpcToidVWBU_czOKCFbV-dkrmCPUx6InD4",
    "name": "desert",
    "mobile": "123456789",
    "type": "N",
    "is_active": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }
```

Comment: some suggest to have a custom auth provider, can read more [in laravel.io forum](https://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5) and [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/replacing-the-laravel-authentication-with-a-custom-authentication).

Comment: tried but didn't help